# ZXing how to return from scannerview? or make the backbutton work without closing the app

Tags: java, android, android-view, qr-code

I have made a simple QR code scanner app with the help of ZXing.

now .. I followed a tutorial and it's all working very well .

except for this one thing, when i successfully scan a QR code it freezes or resumes scanning if I add this line :         `mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);`

But I need my app to go back to the firstscreen/homescreen and close the camera , because the result goes into the `edittext` boxes .But I cannot get this to work.

I have tried looking for answers , and all I could find is convert my app so it uses an intent to scan , but I do not get the process :(

So .. if there's anyone who could help me out with this it would be amazing.
im a beginner at java , but im thinking it cant be hard to just return from where I came from.

this is my one and only activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText edittext;
        button = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        edittext = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        final EditText finalEdittext = edittext;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Clear EditText
                finalEdittext.getText().clear();
            }
        });
        button = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        edittext = findViewById(editText4);

        final EditText finalEdittext1 = edittext;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Clear EditText
                finalEdittext1.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        //handle result
        Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Ordernummer of Locatie");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        updateScannerData(1,result.getText());

        //resume scanning
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

    private void updateScannerData(int scanType, String scannedCode) {

        editText.setText(scannedCode);
    }
}
```

this is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    <Button
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_order"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/scan_locatie"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="@string/button"
        tools:text="Versturen.." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/scan_qr"
        tools:text="scan qr code" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

im thinking of a bit of code like `exit.mScannerview` or something but i don't know .

I want to avoid using the intent solution , because I would need a step by step guide and its not found . Thank you all for those who try to help me out.

**EDIT:**  by adding this code : `startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
this.finish();`

**EDIT2** recreate() works also , but i need a value to be displayed and that gets reset with both methods , anyone knows a trick?

it works like i want , but only is my scan result not being put into edittext field , as coded in updatescannerdata function , HOW ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have also this problem.
I viewed another apps and how they do it. So, how I understand you have minimum two ways:

- create new Activity( or some fragment and use it)
- (myChoise) finish(); // Activity onClick

  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QR_Activity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();

Because I didn't find solve too. RemoveAllViews doesn't work correctly for me, display is frozen.